# Should you clean your data after or before selecting a sample?

Tags: regression, sampling, inference, sample-size, data-preprocessing

Assuming a 500k dataset. For statistical modeling purposes (selecting up to 10% of 500k as a sample). Should I clean the 500k dataset first before selecting a sample or select the sample first and then clean the data?

What if this goes into bigger datasets such as 1 million+ rows?

Comment: The answer likely depends on what you really mean by "statistical modeling purposes."  Sometimes the "cleaning" is part of the modeling and sometimes not.

Comment: Statistical modeling purposes........means building a statistical model. If the dataset is large, I only need roughly a 10% sample. If the full dataset is dirty to begin with, do I clean it first before extracting a sample or do I extract a sample and cleanup if it randomly drew dirty data.

Comment: "Cleaning" might or might not be part of building your model.  That's the issue.

Comment: Assume cleaning is part of the process.

Comment: Then include it in the process!

Comment: I think you're missing the point...WHEN should the data cleaning process start. AFTER I select the sample or BEFORE selecting the sample from the big data set. That is the question.

Comment: You're right--I must be missing the point.  It would be nice if you could be more explicit about it in your post.  Currently, the only relevant information I can find is the vague reference to "statistical modeling purposes."  Maybe if we knew more specifically what those were, it would be possible to offer objective answers.